# DeviceAdmin policies PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC not working

Tags: android

I am working on DeviceAdmin policies implementation, followed below link for implementation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC , In that if we selected PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC password Quality from spinner, while setting password, it should ask for at least one digit but not showing any information to input digit, simply accepting ALPHABETIC, not asking for at least 1 number.I hope this is not expected behaviour,may be i am wrong Please let me know Am i misunderstand PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC?.If i selected PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHABETIC, i tried to give only digits, this time asking for at least 1 letter. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I suffered the same issue. and a bug filed to google.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21732

Answer (score 2):

This is working as intended.  From my comment on the bug: "The request for password quality is a request for the quality to be at *least* as good as requested.  A password with letters is better than a password with numbers, so it is fine for the user to enter a purely alphabetic password in this case."