# Using the Android Device Administration API is it possible to restrict a password to being only numeric

Tags: android, passwords, device-admin

At the request of the client, I am working to implement a password policy that restricts the password to being PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC_COMPLEX and will not permit the passwords to be of a higher quality by containing letters or special characters. Is it possible to specify such a policy using the device administration API?

Comment: Why would you purposely want to make your users use a less secure password?

Comment: It is currently a requirement of the customer. I would like to demonstrate  that we can implement it the way it has been specified before arguing the benefits of having a more complex password.

Comment: No.  Its part of your job as a developer to take stupid requirements like that which make your users less secure and shoot them down.  Not to jump through hoops to build a worse product

Answer (score 0):

I found a question asking why [DeviceAdmin policy PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592949/deviceadmin-policies-password-quality-numeric-not-working)

The closing comment explained why it is not possible to implement a password policy that restricts the password to being only PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC_COMPLEX:

The request for password quality is a request for the quality to be at least as good as requested. A password with letters is better than a password with numbers, so it is fine for the user to enter a purely alphabetic password in this case.

My question is answered. Not only is it undesirable but it is not possible.